# how to print htmlString in loop with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Trying to print my htmlString in the .listing div but I'm only getting the last item in the array, yet the console.log loops correctly. what gives?

```
$.each(json.products, function(index, product) { 

        // build product block
    var htmlString = '<div class="product large-3 columns">';
    //open imgwrap
    htmlString += '<div class="imgwrap">';
    //get img src
    htmlString += ' <img class="item_img" src="http://api.example.com/assets/images/' + product.itemCode + '@2x.jpg" />';
    // close imgwrap
    htmlString += '</div>';
    // open textwrap
    htmlString += '<div class="textwrap">';
    // get productName
    htmlString += '<h1 class="product_headline">' + product.productName + '</h1>' ;
    // get itemCode
    htmlString += '<h4 class="item_id" >' + product.itemCode + '</h4>';
    // get description
    // get price
    // close divs
    htmlString += '</div>';

    console.log(htmlString);
    $('.listing').html(htmlString);

}); //end each
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the contents of `listing` in each iteration, instead you need to append the contents.

When you use [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) it will remove the current contents of the element, then replace it with the passed content. To add the new content after the existing one you can use [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

If you want to clear the `listing` element, you can do it before the beginning of the loop as shown below

```js
$('.listing').html(''); //clear the listing element if needed
$.each(json.products, function(index, product) {

  // build product block
  var htmlString = '<div class="product large-3 columns">';
  //open imgwrap
  htmlString += '<div class="imgwrap">';
  //get img src
  htmlString += ' <img class="item_img" src="http://api.example.com/assets/images/' + product.itemCode + '@2x.jpg" />';
  // close imgwrap
  htmlString += '</div>';
  // open textwrap
  htmlString += '<div class="textwrap">';
  // get productName
  htmlString += '<h1 class="product_headline">' + product.productName + '</h1>';
  // get itemCode
  htmlString += '<h4 class="item_id" >' + product.itemCode + '</h4>';
  // get description
  // get price
  // close divs
  htmlString += '</div>';

  console.log(htmlString);
  $('.listing').append(htmlString); //add the current content to existing one
}); //end each
```

Answer (score 0):

With `.html()` you're replacing the contents after each loop. Instead, append:

`$('.listing').html(htmlString);`

becomes:

`$('.listing').append( $(htmlString) );`