# Creating HTML list using loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I've got an array in Javascript that I want to print to screen which is: (my function for ro[j] is simplified in this example, but that doesn't matter)

```
<div class="result2"></div>
<script>
  var j;
  var ro = [0];
  for(j=0; j <= 49; j++){
    ro[j] = j;
    $('.result2').html(ro[j]);
  }
</script>
```

But this doesn't work as I think it keeps replacing the div with each loop rather than adding to the div. Is there a good way to implement this? I thought you could try something like this:

```
<div class="result2"></div>
<script>
  var j;
  var ro = [0];
  for(j=0; j <= 49; j++){
    ro[j] = j;
    if(j==0){
      $('.result2').html(ro[j]);
    }else{
      var res = $('.result2').val();
      $('.result2').html(res + ro[j]); 
    }
  }
</script>
```

but this doesn't work since you can't seem to call the result of the script midway through the script? Or I just made a mistake, I'm not sure. Any help would be great!

edit: forgot a semicolon

Comment: `var res = $('.result2').html();`

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I was wondering why I couldn't' feed it back in. Thanks, that solves it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to print htmlString in loop with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131633/how-to-print-htmlstring-in-loop-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

A list element (ul or ol) should be used for lists as it's more semantically correct:

```
<ul id="result2"></ul>
```

Using es6 syntax you can append elements to that list like this:

```
const ro = [...Array(49).keys()]; // Just setting up a sample array

for (r of ro) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = r;
  document.getElementById('result2').appendChild(li);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This will place the numbers vertically in the screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="result2"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var ro = [];

        for (var j = 0; j <= 49; j++) {
            ro.push(j);
            $('.result2').append(ro[j] + '<br />');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems very awkward, you should setup ro with 49 entries before looping through it.